# How can I create a Java method that accepts a variable number of arguments?

Tags: java, function, methods, overloading

For example, Java's own `String.format()` supports a variable number of arguments.

```
String.format("Hello %s! ABC %d!", "World", 123);
//=> Hello World! ABC 123!
```

How can I make my own function that accepts a variable number of arguments?

---

Follow-up question:

I'm really trying to make a convenience shortcut for this:

```
System.out.println( String.format("...", a, b, c) );
```

So that I can call it as something less verbose like this:

```
print("...", a, b, c);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You could write a convenience method:

```
public PrintStream print(String format, Object... arguments) {
    return System.out.format(format, arguments);
}
```

But as you can see, you've simply just renamed `format` (or `printf`).

Here's how you could use it:

```
private void printScores(Player... players) {
    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; ++i) {
        Player player = players[i];
        String name   = player.getName();
        int    score  = player.getScore();
        // Print name and score followed by a newline
        System.out.format("%s: %d%n", name, score);
    }
}

// Print a single player, 3 players, and all players
printScores(player1);
System.out.println();
printScores(player2, player3, player4);
System.out.println();
printScores(playersArray);

// Output
Abe: 11

Bob: 22
Cal: 33
Dan: 44

Abe: 11
Bob: 22
Cal: 33
Dan: 44
```

Note there's also the similar `System.out.printf` method that behaves the same way, but if you peek at the implementation, `printf` just calls `format`, so you might as well use `format` directly.

- [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)
- [`PrintStream#format(String format, Object... args)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)
- [`PrintStream#printf(String format, Object... args)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: So this has already been implemented? Should I just use it as `PrintStream.print("...", a, b, c)`? Provide a usage example and I will mark this as accepted answer :)

Comment: Yep, this is already provided on `PrintStream`, which `System.out` happens to be :D You can use either `printf` or `format`

Comment: @NateW. How does it differs from `private void printScores(Player[] players) {}`?

Comment: @M.S. In your example, the only valid argument to the method would be an array. On the other hand, with a vararg parameter, an array, a single element, and multiple comma-separated elements are all valid. There are more ways to call it.

Answer (score 26):

This is known as varargs see the link [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) for more details

In past java releases, a method that took an arbitrary number of values required you to create an array and put the values into the array prior to invoking the method. For example, here is how one used the MessageFormat class to format a message:

```
Object[] arguments = {
    new Integer(7),
    new Date(),
    "a disturbance in the Force"
};
    String result = MessageFormat.format(
        "At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet "
         + "{0,number,integer}.", arguments);
```

It is still true that multiple arguments must be passed in an array, but the varargs feature automates and hides the process. Furthermore, it is upward compatible with preexisting APIs. So, for example, the MessageFormat.format method now has this declaration:

```
public static String format(String pattern,
                            Object... arguments);
```

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the Java guide on [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

You can create a method as shown below. Simply call `System.out.printf` instead of `System.out.println(String.format(...`.

```
public static void print(String format, Object... args) {
    System.out.printf(format, args);
}
```

Alternatively, you can just use a [static import](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) if you want to type as little as possible. Then you don't have to create your own method:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

out.printf("Numer of apples: %d", 10);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is just an extension to above provided answers.

1. There can be only one variable argument in the method.
2. Variable argument (varargs) must be the last argument.

Clearly explained [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/varargs) and rules to follow to use **Variable Argument**.

Answer (score 2):

The following will create a variable length set of arguments of the type of string:

```
print(String arg1, String... arg2)
```

You can then refer to `arg2` as an array of Strings. This is a new feature in Java 5.

Answer (score 0):

The variable arguments must be the last of the parameters specified in your function declaration. If you try to specify another parameter after the variable arguments, the compiler will complain since there is no way to determine how many of the parameters actually belong to the variable argument.

```
void print(final String format, final String... arguments) {
    System.out.format( format, arguments );
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can pass all similar type values in the function while calling it.
In the function **definition** put a **array** so that all the passed values can be **collected in that array**.
e.g. 
.

```
static void demo (String ... stringArray) {
  your code goes here where read the array stringArray
}
```