# Strings to String[] in Java

Tags: java

I've method like this,

```
public void beforeTest(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
   x = getURL(a, b, c, d);
   --------
   --------
}
```

I now want to pass String[] instead of individual Strings as arguments type, so tried this,

```
public void beforeTest(String[] args){
   x = getURL(a, b, c, d);
   --------
   --------
}
```

and passed a,b,c,d as command line arguments, my code isn't working, is it the right approach?

Thank you all, I did try getURL(args[0].......) approach and unfortunately I'm still getting the same error,

[testng] FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod beforeTest [testng] org.testng.TestNGException: [testng] Method beforeTest requires 1 parameters but 4 were supplied in the @Configuration annotation.

By the way, my getURL method is defined as below,

```
protected String getURL(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
   if (condition){
      return a
   } else if (condition) {
      return b
   } ....
```

Comment: you have an args array parameter, but then you don't use it in your call to getURL().  So, what is the point?  Don't you want, "x = getURL(args[0], args[1],,, ), etc?

Comment: `getURL(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);`

Comment: use `getURL( args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3] )` but you probably want to do some checking before to make sure you got the right number of arguments.

Comment: if you use `beforeSuite(String ... args)` you don't have to touch client code.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607353/how-to-create-java-method-that-accepts-variable-number-of-arguments

Comment: I've updated my post after trying the above approach

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
String a = args[0];
String b = args[1];
String c = args[2];
String d = args[3];
```

Passing of the 4 strings as command line arguments is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use varargs instead. It allows you to treat the input as an array and doesn't require the caller to create an array himself.

```
public void beforeSuite(String... args){
   x = getURL(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
}
```

You can call this like this:

```
beforeSuite("test", "test", "test again", "more tests", "even more tests");
// Notice how I can specify more than 4 (or less, or equal to 4) strings
// without changing the method signature
```

The major issue is accessing your variables though: `args[0]` instead of `args`. `args` is just an array, but `args[0]` is a value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think shortest way to do that is

```
x = getURL(args);
```

This will only work if `getURL` is declared as `getURL(String...)` or `getURL(String[])`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void beforeSuite(String[] args){
   x = getURL(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
   --------
   --------
}
```

But why not give `getUrl` similar type of signature with parameter type `String[]`. Then you could again pass the `args` invoking `getUrl(args)`. You can also declare both method with `varargs` parameter: `beforeSuite(String... args)` and `getURL(String... args)`

Answer (score 0):

To do what you need you have to change your method.

```
public void beforeSuite(String...args){
   x = getURL(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
   --------
   --------
}
```

But keep in mind that this definition (`String...args`) on a method can have N number of arguments, which means that if you pass less than 4 arguments you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.