# Using unspecified number of arguments in another method

Tags: java, method-call

Sorry but I'm not able to phrase this question properly without an example. Say `oneMethod` has such a signature:

```
void oneMethod(String... strings);
```

I call `oneMethod` by

```
void callOneMethod(int numStrings) {
    oneMethod("s" + 0, "s" + 1, ..., "s" + (numStrings - 1));
}
```

How should I write my `callOneMethod`?

Also, I very much appreciate it if anyone can help rephrase this question better :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Java method that accepts variable number of arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607353/how-to-create-java-method-that-accepts-variable-number-of-arguments)

Comment: @Dima thanks for the reference. However my problem is more about how to pass unspecified arguments into a varargs-method at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strings` parameter is very similar to an array parameter. Therefore you can create an array to pass to `oneMethod`:

```
void callOneMethod(int numStrings) {
    String[] a = new String[numStrings];
    for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
        a[i] = "s" + i;
    }
    oneMethod(a);
}
```

#### Clarification

Of course still your `oneMethod(String... strings)` method is used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I'm passing all `numStrings` number of strings into `oneMethod` at the same time. So what arguments `oneMethod` accepts is decided at runtime...

Comment: @goldfrapp04 this answer is the correct one. This allows you to pass whatever number of arguments you want. What is the issue?

Comment: Oh! ok I guess I didn't understand varargs clearly. So essentially it sees the arguments as an array?

Comment: @goldfrapp04: Form inside a method with a vararg parameter you treat it as a array. When calling the method you can pass either an array (like in my code snipplet) or arbitrary number of arguments have the right type (e.g. `oneMethod("a", "b", "c")`).