# How to make method with infinite parameters like String.format() in Java?

Tags: java, string, methods, arguments, parameter-passing

In Java , String has a method called Format and in that method you can add as much parameters as you can. 
For example: `String.format("%d and %s",value,text)` and `String.format("%s and %s , and %d",title,text,value)`

Thus this method can have many parameters with different classes without having an error. How can I make a method like that? is it possible in Generics and Recursion ?

Comment: Look for varargs (you could have check the method signature to have your answer).

Comment: @AlexisC. Thank you! Then it is generics :P

Comment: It's not related to generics. The method just takes an `Object...` as parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607353/how-to-create-java-method-that-accepts-variable-number-of-arguments

Comment: varargs is the solution