# best way to pass many arguments to a method in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, variadic-functions

I have a method

```
makeSomeObject(String a,String b,KeyValue...){}

//method call
Obj.makeSomeObject(stringa,stringb,new KeyValue(String1,String2),new KeyValue(String3,String4),new KeyValue(String4,String5));
```

How can I refactor my makeSomeObject() method so that I can elegantly pass multiple KeyValue pairs to it so that the method call is cleaner and easy to read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Java method that accepts variable number of arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607353/how-to-create-java-method-that-accepts-variable-number-of-arguments)

Comment: I know how to use varargs and pass multiple values to an array. I am already doing it in my method call.Read the question carefully!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a builder for `Obj`, which will give you a more fluent way of constructing the `Obj` than using the static method in your question.

```
public class ObjBuilder {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private List<KeyValue> keyValues = new ArrayList<>();

    private ObjBuilder() {}

    public static ObjBuilder obj() {
        return new ObjBuilder();
    }

    public ObjBuilder withA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
        return this;
    }

    public ObjBuilder withB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
        return this;
    }

    public ObjBuilder withKeyValue(KeyValue keyValue) {
        this.keyValues.add(keyValue);
        return this;
    }

    public Obj build() {
        // whatever Obj.makeSomeObject does to create the Obj instance
    }
}
```

Then when you need to create an `Obj`

```
Obj obj = ObjBuilder.obj()
            .withA("some String")
            .withB("some String")
            .withKeyValue(new KeyValue("A", "B"))
            .withKeyValue(new KeyValue("C", "D"))
            .build();
```

Obviously using this over the static varargs method in your question is largely a stylistic choice

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Map` Or a `List` of KeyValue

```
makeSomeObject(String a,String b,Map<String,String> keyValue)
{
}

Map<String,String> keyValue=new HashMap<String,String> ();
keyValue.put(key1,value1);
keyValue.put(key2,value2);
.................
Obj.makeSomeObject(stringa,stringb,keyValue);
```

OR,

```
makeSomeObject(String a,String b,List<KeyValue> keyValues)

List list=new ArrayList<KeyValue>();
list.add(new KeyValue(a,b));
list.add(new KeyValue(c,d));
.........
Obj.makeSomeObject(stringa,stringb,list);
```

Answer (score 2):

If it has more than 3 (I personally do not prefer more than 3 as it causes readability issues for me), You can always wrap the args in the form of an object.
Class can have members like `String a, String b, Map<K,V> vals` (please use better names for the members).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [variable argument](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-variable-arguments/)

```
makeSomeObject(String a,String b,KeyValue... arguments) {}
```

Example:-

```
makeSomeMethod("firstString", "secondString", new KeyValue(1,"one"),new KeyValue(2, "two"));

public static void makeSomeMethod(String a,String b,KeyValue... keyValues){
    for(KeyValue kv: keyValues)
        //Anything you want with kv
        System.out.println(kv.toString());
}
```

Comment: If you read the code fragments in the question you can see that they are already using varargs. The question being asked is about alternative ways to pass multiple parameters