# Chose amount of parameters to call in a method?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, parameters

While I was attempting to make a method that runs calculations and returns the binary value for a small project I'm working on; I was trying to have the method parameters include all of the values to add together, but when doing so I realized I don't know how to do so without using an array of some sort.

Is it possible to have the parameters in the following method `addBinary` change based on the amount I wish to add?

```
public int addBinary() // I want these parameters to have all integers I wish to add
{
    // Calculations go here //
}
```

Essentially, if I wish to run the program and add 5 values the first time and 25 the next; how would I get all of the values into the method without creating an array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607353/how-to-create-java-method-that-accepts-variable-number-of-arguments You have to variable number of arguments in this case

Comment: What particular reason do you have for not wanting to make an array?

Comment: What you are asking for is called [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html), short for variable number of arguments.

Comment: @nhouser9 Really just a lack of knowledge. I know I'd use an arraylist and I know I'd simply add the numbers to it each time. But I don't know how to use an arraylist in a method; so I decided if there's a way to do it _without_ an arraylist I'd like to know.

Comment: No need of using arraylist also. Just use a simple array if you don't want to modify it anywhere in between.

Comment: @Infinitylsx So you want to pass variable number of parameters and at the same time not use array or arraylist.

Comment: @FallAndLearn Alright - It's late and some reason I made myself think I _needed_ an arraylist. Ill try it out with a regular array in the morning.

Comment: I don't think varargs will help you here.  varargs helps when the _called_ method doesn't know how many parameters it will get, but the _calling_ statement does know.  It sounds more like even the caller doesn't know, and could call with a different number of values each time (if I'm interpreting correctly).  In that case, you really need an `ArrayList`.  As for not knowing how to use an `ArrayList` in a method--I'm not sure what you mean.  You just use it.  If you try to use it and can't get it right, post another question.

Comment: @abj I really just mean I've not done enough with ArrayLists yet. I'll look around on here for something similar to what I'm looking for and if I can't find it I'll post another question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are not thinking of using arrays here. Just pass an `array` as a parameter and do the calculations you want to do.

```
public int addBinary(int a[]) 
{
     for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            sum+=a[i];
     return sum;
}
```

Or by using an arraylist

```
public int addBinary(ArrayList m) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < m.size(); i++)
          sum += m.get(i);
    return sum;
}
```

Link for the code [Ideone](http://ideone.com/2Fmhqo)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use an arraylist if I don't know how big I'd want the array to be? Or would I just initiate the array as the length of values entered each time the program is ran?

Comment: It depends on your need. You can definitely use an arraylist if there are variable number of elements.

Comment: @Infinitylsx If you know how many values there will be before you initiate the array, you can do it that way.  But you don't always know.  Suppose your job is to accept input from the user until they enter -1 which is an "end of list" signal.  Now you don't know ahead of time how big your array will need to be, so an `ArrayList` is much better.

Comment: @abj Although it's more inefficient, could you not create a value `temp` and have it be equal to the total amount of times you enter a value that is not -1, and then just declare `int[] anArray = new int[X];`?
-
But yes, I do think I would use an ArrayList just for the ease of being able to just use the add method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable number of arguments in the method definiton(using ellipses i.e `...` ) like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static int add(int ...arr)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            sum+=arr[i];
        return sum;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(add(1, 2, 3, 4));
        System.out.println(add(1, 2, 3));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10 
6
```

https://ideone.com/PHL8Lb

Answer (score 0):

You can use varargs for this

```
void testapp(String ...studentsName){       
     for (int i = 0; i < studentsName.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(studentsName[i]);
    }
 }
```