# Abstract method for multi parameter

Tags: java, android

I want to create a method with multi-arguments as an abstract one. For example for the error message I need 4 arguments to show where for a simple message I need only 2 and so on. In fact, I want to make an abstract method which forced to implement it but allows to making methods with a different number of arguments. Is it possible to do such work? If no how should I can approach it?

**Abstract Class**

```
public abstract void ShowDialog(AppCompatActivity dialogContext, Object... args);
```

**Implementation**

```
public void ShowDialog(AppCompatActivity dialogContext,String title,String message) 
{ //Some code }
```

Comment: Your implementation method signature doesn't match the abstract one. It's not clear what you're asking. If you're asking, as you seem to be, whether you can _specialize_ when you override a method, the answer is no, you can't. When you override you must be able to accept the parameters of the method you're overriding.

Comment: @pvg Thanks. So what's the best way to create such method? Should I use Design Patterns or there are other ways to do it by Java?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'such a method' so this is a little difficult to answer. Perhaps you can edit your question clarifying what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Again, your overriden/implementing method cannot be a specialization of the method you're overriding. If you started with 'it must be able to take an array of Object as last parameter', you can't say well, in this subclass implementation it will only take a string. That's simply not how compile-time, static typing in Java works.

Answer (score -2):

I find this post on Stack: [How to create Java method that accepts variable number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607353/how-to-create-java-method-that-accepts-variable-number-of-arguments)

Take a look.