# Grabbing different variable names with one line of code

Tags: java, arraylist, dynamic-variables

I'm trying to use one line of code to grab any number of variables so that I can scale up easily without having to add tons of code.

The line that says `p+(a+1).add(a)` is what I'm looking at in particular

```
public void arraylistvariables()
{
    ArrayList<String> p1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> p2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    int d = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++)
    {
        p+(a+1).add(a);
    }
}
```

I feel that it should grab each individual ArrayList but it is returning an error message that says "not a statement"

Comment: statically typed languages such as Java don't allow access to variable names (that would be dynamic typing, the opposite). Use a list of lists to solve your problem instead.

Comment: Or possibly use a method with a variable number of arguments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607353/how-to-create-java-method-that-accepts-variable-number-of-arguments

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support dynamically retrieving a variable name.  Use a List or Array to hold the instances you wish to leverage.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible in a statically typed language like Java. `a` is a variable, so the compiler cannot assert that there is definitely a variable called `p{a}`.

What are looking for is more in-line with the behaviour of a dynamic language, though even some of them may not allow you to do this.

In Java, the idiomatic way to do something like this would probably be to have a list of lists. First, get the list of strings, then add to that. We sidestep having `p1` and `p2`, they are now just elements of the list of lists.

```
public void arraylistvariables()
{
    List<List<String>> allTheLists = Arrays.asList(
        new ArrayList<>(),
        new ArrayList<>()
    );

    int d = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < allTheLists.size(); a++)
    {
        allTheLists.get(a).add(Integer.toString(a));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to do is achievable since variables are not like strings, you can not concatenate variables.

However, here is a possible solution :

```
    ArrayList<String> p1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> p2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> p = new ArrayList<>();
    p.add(p1);
    p.add(p2);

    for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++)
    {
        p.get(a).add(""+a);
    }
```